# CS50 speller problem segmentation fault first, then I found it failed to load the dictionary correctly

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable, cs50

100% newbie in coding, this is a really tough problem-set for me.
Took me few days to finally got my program to compile. However I am getting segmentation fault when I actually running the program. So I tried to delete the function with error and see how it goes, to my surprise the segmentation fault no longer show up and did actually ran. Turns out my program does not properly created a hash table out of the dictionary.
So my guess, the root problem is that my check function was trying to assign table[index] which does not exist to my temp node and hence gave me segmentation fault, was my guess correct?
So my next bet is to get my program to load the dictionary correctly, however I am not capable of spotting any errors after repeatedly checking the load function, did I miss anything?
hereby attached my code:

```
// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;
//set up counter to count no. of word in dictionary
int counter;
// Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 26;

// Initialize Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // get hash index
    int index=hash(word);
    //loop to run thru the linked list and do comparison
    for(node* temp=table[index];temp->next!=NULL;temp=temp->next)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(temp->word, word)==0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // the very basic ,slow hash function indexing A-Z to 0-26
    char A= toupper(word[0]);
    int Z= A-65;
    return (Z);
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *file=fopen(dictionary ,"r");
    if(!file)
    {
    return false;
    }
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    while(fscanf(file,"%s",word)!=EOF)
    {
        //make new node n
        node*n=malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(n==NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        //input data into node n
        strcpy(n->word,word);
        n->next=NULL;
        //get index from hash function
        int index=hash(word);
        //check linked list in hash table ,if empty> assign n in linked list
        if(table[index]==NULL)
        {
        table[index]=n;
        counter++;
        }
        //update linked list in hash table
        else
        {
        n->next=table[index];
        table[index]=n;
        counter++;
        }
        return true;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    if (counter!=0)
    {
        return (counter);
    }
    else
    {
    return 0;
    }
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        while(table[i]!=NULL)
        {
            node* temp=table[i]->next;
            free(table[i]);
            table[i]=temp;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

First, I ran a valgrind for debug and i got the following error message:

```
Invalid read of size 8
==24218==    at 0x4019BC: check (dictionary.c:32)
==24218==    by 0x4015FB: main (speller.c:113)
==24218==  Address 0x30 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
...
==11431== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

line 8 was in check function

```
    for(node* temp=table[index];temp->next!=NULL;temp=temp->next)
```

And the program ran after I temporarily set the check function to simply return true, it ran and gave the following result:

```
WORDS MISSPELLED:     0
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  1
WORDS IN TEXT:        17756
TIME IN load:         0.00
TIME IN check:        0.02
TIME IN size:         0.00
TIME IN unload:       0.00
TIME IN TOTAL:        0.02
```

seems that it is having problem loading dictionary into a hash table
hopefully the program will run normally after load function corrected.

update : as requested, hereby attached the main program ,however it was written by staffs of CS50, unlikely to be the problem

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // Structures for timing data
    struct rusage before, after;

    // Benchmarks
    double time_load = 0.0, time_check = 0.0, time_size = 0.0, time_unload = 0.0;

    // Determine dictionary to use
    char *dictionary = (argc == 3) ? argv[1] : DICTIONARY;

    // Load dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool loaded = load(dictionary);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Exit if dictionary not loaded
    if (!loaded)
    {
        printf("Could not load %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to load dictionary
    time_load = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Try to open text
    char *text = (argc == 3) ? argv[2] : argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(text, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Prepare to report misspellings
    printf("\nMISSPELLED WORDS\n\n");

    // Prepare to spell-check
    int index = 0, misspellings = 0, words = 0;
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Spell-check each word in text
    char c;
    while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file))
    {
        // Allow only alphabetical characters and apostrophes
        if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0))
        {
            // Append character to word
            word[index] = c;
            index++;

            // Ignore alphabetical strings too long to be words
            if (index > LENGTH)
            {
                // Consume remainder of alphabetical string
                while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file) && isalpha(c));

                // Prepare for new word
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        // Ignore words with numbers (like MS Word can)
        else if (isdigit(c))
        {
            // Consume remainder of alphanumeric string
            while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file) && isalnum(c));

            // Prepare for new word
            index = 0;
        }

        // We must have found a whole word
        else if (index > 0)
        {
            // Terminate current word
            word[index] = '\0';

            // Update counter
            words++;

            // Check word's spelling
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
            bool misspelled = !check(word);
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

            // Update benchmark
            time_check += calculate(&before, &after);

            // Print word if misspelled
            if (misspelled)
            {
                printf("%s\n", word);
                misspellings++;
            }

            // Prepare for next word
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    // Check whether there was an error
    if (ferror(file))
    {
        fclose(file);
        printf("Error reading %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Close text
    fclose(file);

    // Determine dictionary's size
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    unsigned int n = size();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Calculate time to determine dictionary's size
    time_size = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Unload dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool unloaded = unload();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Abort if dictionary not unloaded
    if (!unloaded)
    {
        printf("Could not unload %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to unload dictionary
    time_unload = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Report benchmarks
    printf("\nWORDS MISSPELLED:     %d\n", misspellings);
    printf("WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  %d\n", n);
    printf("WORDS IN TEXT:        %d\n", words);
    printf("TIME IN load:         %.2f\n", time_load);
    printf("TIME IN check:        %.2f\n", time_check);
    printf("TIME IN size:         %.2f\n", time_size);
    printf("TIME IN unload:       %.2f\n", time_unload);
    printf("TIME IN TOTAL:        %.2f\n\n",
           time_load + time_check + time_size + time_unload);

    // Success
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is your `main`? Post a [mcve].

Comment: Aside: I am baffled by the need for function `unsigned size(void)`. It just returns `counter`.

Comment: the main function was written by the staffs of CS50 program, I will post it in no time.

Comment: I guess the counter function is for their evaluation purpose

Comment: Weather Vane's comment was probably about the fact the the function is needlessly complicated. `if (x != 0) return x; else return 0;` can be written as just `return x;`. You've got a similar treatment of two cases where you insert a new node at the head, where you could use the same code whether the head is null or not. It's not wrong, but a bit roundabout.

Comment: Are all words guaranteed to begin with a letter? If not, your hash code might produce illegal array indices. Perhaps you should reserve a 27th slot for "not a letter" or just return `tolower(s[0]) % 26`.

Comment: @MOehm I think all words are assumed to be letter beginning for simplicity of the task

Comment: 1. Your `hash()` is very poor, makes searching `linear`. 2. What's the word's `LENGTH` value?

Comment: 3. What's `return true;` doing in `load()`  while-loop after inserting a word?

Comment: Search stack-overflow with `[c] [cs50] spell` you'll get several questions with suggestions & answers

Comment: Also there is https://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @SparKot A big thank you! turns out it is my return true after the do while loop screwing the whole thing up! 
yes I know my hash function is very poor, since I am a beginner ,want to make sure everything else works fine before doing actually improvement! and now that is my next task! thank you again !